# Hide Copy option from clipboard and sidemenu on QLPreviewController

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, qlpreviewcontroller

I want to hide the copy option on the side menu of QLPreview and on click the clipboard show copy option to select and copy text, how to disable these two option in QLPreview.

[Demo Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IW6yY.jpg)

I tried different approached but none of them is working and there is no delegate method for the same. Disable edit method hides other option but still copy is coming on the side menu.